# Facebook for Android: Session an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to FB SDK for android. I followed the sample tutorials as is. But I'm getting this error:

This is the code for MainFragment.class:

```
 private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private TextView userInfoTextView;
private Button shareButton;
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = 
            savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
    }

    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "email"));
    // This opens a webview to type your email/username and password
    //authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
    userInfoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);

    shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishStory();        
        }
    });



    return view;
}


private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
    StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");

    // Example: typed access (name)
    // - no special permissions required
    userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", 
        user.getName()));

    // Example: typed access (birthday)
    // - requires user_birthday permission
    userInfo.append(String.format("Firstname: %s\n\n", 
        user.getInnerJSONObject() ));

    userInfo.append(String.format("Username: %s\n\n", 
        user.getUsername()));

    userInfo.append(String.format("ID: %s\n\n", 
            user.getId()));

    userInfo.append(String.format("Email: %s\n\n", 
            user.asMap().get("email")));

    userInfo.append(String.format("Gender: %s\n\n", 
            user.asMap().get("gender") ));


    return userInfo.toString();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

//private boolean isLoggedIn = false; // by default assume not logged in

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        //isLoggedIn = true;
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
                state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishStory();
        }

        // Request user data and show the results
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // Display the parsed user info
                userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
            }
        });



    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        //isLoggedIn = false;
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}

private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){
        // Check for publish permissions    

        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {

            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;

            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);

            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

            return;

        }



        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");

        postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");

        postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");

        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");

        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");



        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {

            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                JSONObject graphResponse = response

                                          .getGraphObject()

                                          .getInnerJSONObject();

                String postId = null;

                try {

                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.i(TAG,

                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());

                }

                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

                if (error != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity()

                        .getApplicationContext(),

                        error.getErrorMessage(),

                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()

                            .getApplicationContext(), 

                            postId,

                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

        };



        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 

                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);



        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);

        task.execute();

    }

}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

I just checked all the questions here on StackOverflow similar to mine but I didn't find one that solves my problem. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Old version (Deprecated). And the problem you were facing is , You already started a session and you were requesting a new session. Try the following sample(without deprecations) this might help you.
In OnResume() I mentioned `Session session = Session.getActiveSession();`  which gets the active session instead of requesting a new one. This might solve your problem of session management.

```
package com.example.integration;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginButton fbLoginBtn;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fbLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        fbLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
            edit.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
            edit.putString("expires", session.getExpirationDate() + "");
            edit.commit();
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                        String lastName = user.getLastName();
                        String id = user.getId();
                        String email = (String) user.asMap().get("email");

                        Log.i("facebookid", id);
                        Log.i("firstName", firstName);
                        Log.i("lastName", lastName);
                        Log.i("AccessToken", session.getAccessToken());
                        Log.i("Email", email);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", firstName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            });

        } 

        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(MainActivity.this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```